# Validation Techniques - Open to Discussion

Tags: php, validation, xss, csrf

So searched the internet and stackoverflow to find anything related that could have been discussed before or any article, i was unable to find any, so i found myself creating the topic.

I am working on a project where i make a lot of ajax request on POST. Therfor validation plays an important role as it MUST be.

So i created some Validation functions as listed below

```
   //only numeric (integer) regexp [1-9]
   Validation::isInteger($a);
   //numeric and alphabetic (integer&string) regexp [a-z1-9]
   Validation::isAlphaNum($c);
   //(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday) Regexp
   Validation::isDay($d);
   //Array numeric (integer) Regexp
   Validation::isArrayNum($sortTo);
```

I used it in my code like this, But this seems so ugly!
in Model:

```
 if(Validation::isInteger($a))
 {
   if(Validation::isAlphaNum($c))
   {
     if(Validation::isDay($d))
     {
       if(Validation::isArrayNum($sortTo))
       {
          //do process here!
 }}}}
```

Then i thought about doing validation like this maybe; Not sure if its safe!
in Model:

```
   if(!Validation::isInteger($a) &&
      !Validation::isAlphaNum($c) &&            
      !Validation::isDay($d) && 
      !Validation::isArrayNum($sortTo)) exit;

      //do process here anyway without "if" closure if you dont pass validation above you won't see me!
```

**My questions are:**

1. Should i validate data in Controller or model? Does it matter?
2. Is my second approach safe?
3. How do you validate your data? (whats your design of code)
4. What other methods/techniques i can use to prettify this uglyness.

**NOTE**: i am not too concerned about throwing errors due to validation fails.

EDIT:(23.02.2014) However i found a video that has great explanations about Validation by phpacademy in youtube.com if you are having same kind of problems with validation or want to have an idea i really recommend you watch it.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWon2iC-cQ0&index=13&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc

Comment: you could use flags and pass them and string to one function that does all validation.

Comment: Not that it is actually part of the question, but if you are doing all tests in one conditional it should be `||` not `&&` (to get the same as nested if above). Or get rid of the not operators.

Comment: 1) do negative check and return/throw exception if an error found to avoid the ugly nested structure
2) it's a good thing to use form objects that can contain the elements that can be decorated with validators. Have a look at some frameworks (Zend, Symfony etc) to get an idea how it should work

Comment: i came down to solution where i create rules bunch of rules in an array and pass them into my validate check function along with $_POST. Then filter data there and add errors if caught any.
then simply if(count(errors) flag = false; else flag = true;

Answer (score 1):

Many frameworks introduce the concept of model validation as its own class or module. For example you have a model and you have validation rules against that model. The task of validating a model based on rules can live within a high level validation class. The rules themselves can live within their own classes as well. Frameworks such as Symfony2 allow validation rules on models via config or annotations. It would be well worth the time to research how [Symfony2 uses validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html).